# Deadlock when multiple stored procedures are reading and updating the same tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I have been experiencing the following error when using SQL Server 2019.

> Transaction (Process ID XXX) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

The error occurs when the following procedures are executed:

- Procedure 1 - has begin and end transaction, has try and catch - on success, executes procedure 2;
- Procedure 2 - has begin and end transaction, has try and catch - on success, executes procedure 3;
- Procedure 3 - execute insert/update/delete operation without transaction and no try-catch, after that execute procedure 4;
- Procedure 4 - execute insert/update/delete operation without transaction and no try-catch.

Procedures 1, 2 and 3 are executed from only one place in the interface (procedures 2 and 3 are only called from procedure 1).

Procedure 4 is executed from two places in the interface.

Are the transactions wrong? Should there be a transaction only in the first procedure? Should all procedures have a try-catch?

Any idea how I can find the cause of the error?

Comment: They shouldn't be deadlocking themselves if they're in the same transaction. Are one or more of the stored procedures using exec tricks to run code in a different @@SPID?

Comment: Without seeing more detail this is impossible to diagnose. To diagnose a deadlock, we'd need at a minimum: the XDL (XML) deadlock graph; the SQL code for each of these processes (from `BEGIN TRAN` to `COMMIT` if you have, otherwise just the statement that deadlocked, and if a `EXEC` is inside a transaction we need the whole procedure); also the relevant tables *and all indexes* definitions; and please share the query plans for these procedures vie https://pastetheplan.com. Without all this it's impossible to properly diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

try using transaction processing in each stored procedure

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN;
    UPDATE accounts set current_balance=current_balance - 100 where account_id=1;
    insert into transactions values(1,-100, GETDATE());

    Update accounts set current_balance=current_balance + 100 where account_id=5;
    insert into transactions values(5,100,GETDATE());
COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```